# Why is android emulator ignoring my manifest permissions?

Tags: android, android-permissions

After fighting a couple of hours to read something from the sdcard using ADT v22.3.0-887826 I only can think that my manifest is been ignored. Adding 4 lines to the hello world project.

One in the manifest

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></permission>
```

Three in the MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String permission = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    int res = getBaseContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    System.out.println("permission:"+(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));            
}
```

The output is "permission:false"

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but do you have an SDcard image for your AVD? They do not come with one "out of the package" so-to-speak, could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

instead of

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

"permission" tag is used when you want your app to give some permissions to other apps.

"uses-permission" is used when YOU ask for some permission, ex read_external_storage, internet, sensors, etc.

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is needed since Kit Kat but is included with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I prefer not to ask for writing

Comment: Opps sorry, the main thing is "uses-permission" instead of "permision". It's a copy mistake from my code :))

<permission/> is used when you want your app to give some permissions to other apps for some reasson.
<usses-permission/> is used when YOU ask for some permission, ex read_external_storage, internet, sensors, etc...

Answer (score 0):

> Why is android emulator ignoring my manifest permissions?

You don't have your permissions set correctly, should be like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

the links below should better help you understand why your permissions should be written like that.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html